# I need help fixing a batch script I've created

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

```bash
:test
powershell -Command "exit (Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams | Select-String -Pattern 'InstanceName').length"
set nMons=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %errorlevel% equ 2 start C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat
timeout 10
goto:test
```

What this loop does, is check every 10 seconds for the number of monitors connected to my PC, and restart a certain app if it detects more than 2 monitors, afterwards the script shuts down.

I need help keeping this script running but I only want it to restart the app when the monitor count changes.

This script runs at startup, when there is 1 monitor connected to my PC.

From this point forward it keeps checking my monitor count until a second monitor is connected, and when it finds a second monitor, it restarts the app and it shuts down right away.

All good for now, but from this point forward, I want the script to remain active, to keep checking for monitors, just in case one of the monitors is disconnected and reconnected later on, when it should restart the app once more.

My issue is, if the script remains active after the second monitor is connected, it keeps searching for monitors every 10 seconds, and because there are already 2 monitors connected, it will restart the app every 10 seconds.

How can I avoid this?

I want the script to take a break from checking my monitor count after it found the second monitor, until there is an actual difference made to the monitor count, like one monitor getting disconnected.

Comment: Would in not make more sense to check for the number of active monitors, i.e. ```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Exit (Get-CimInstance -NameSpace Root\WMI -Query \"SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams WHERE Active = 'TRUE'\").Active.Length"```

Comment: So my script is not already checking the numbers of the monitors? The point is that once the 2 monitors are ON the app starts and the scripts is closing. When the monitor is turned off and then is turned ON again the script is not running anymore. I want it to search all the time 2 monitors even if there are already 2 monitor and only when is 1 OFF and then turned On to launch the app. I hope i was clear. Im verry new to this. Thank you!

Comment: Your script is counting the number of instance names returned. Some of those may not be active. My idea only counts the number which returned as active. Commonly, I doubt if it makes much difference in most scenarios, but my idea is certainly more robust. I know what your question is, there is no need to repeat it in the comments, I'm simply offering you advice to improve your code and its robustness, by substituting `powershell -Command "exit (Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams | Select-String -Pattern 'InstanceName').length"` with my commented code.

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of `set nMons=%ERRORLEVEL%`? You don't appear to be using `%nMons%` anywhere else. If you are not, then just remove that line, otherwise change `if %errorlevel% equ 2` to `If %nMons% Equ 2`.

Comment: That is your question, and as I've already told you, there is no need to keep repeating it in the comments. The comment section is for advice, or to request additional information etc. Answers are posted in the answer section. also you didn't specify whether there would ever be a chance that more than two monitors would still need to trigger the batch file, so perhaps `Equ 2` would be better as `Gtr 1`. Also I would guess that using `Call "C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat"` or just `"C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat"` would also be preferred to `start C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your script to know the number of expected monitors to realize any change. Use a variable to save the old value to compare it with a new value:

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM get first number (at startup)
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Exit (Get-CimInstance -NameSpace Root\WMI -Query \"SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams WHERE Active = 'TRUE'\").Active.Length"
set OldNumber=%errorlevel%

:loop
timeout 10 >nul
REM get CurrentNumber
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Exit (Get-CimInstance -NameSpace Root\WMI -Query \"SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams WHERE Active = 'TRUE'\").Active.Length"
set CurrentNumber=%errorlevel%
echo DEBUG: CurrentNumber/old = %CurrentNumber%/%OldNumber%
if %CurrentNumber% gtr %OldNumber% (
   set OldNumber=%CurrentNumber%
   echo Found a new monitor
)
if %CurrentNumber% lss %OldNumber% (
   set OldNumber=%CurrentNumber%
   echo A monitor is now missing
)
goto :loop
```

Just add the commands that should execute when a monitor connects or disconnects.

Comment: Thank you for answer!! I added the command start C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat after first IF when the number its gtr and once its found that its greater is closing the script, its not searching anymore if im doing any changes. How can I make it search but without starting the app over again if its already open.

Comment: Take a look at `tasklist /?`. You can pipe it to `find` and react according to the `%errorlevel%` or conditional executing like `tasklist | find "YourApp" && echo already running || echo not running`

Comment: ok, and once the script found the app is not running and starting the app with start C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat, the script is closing. What is the command to keep running and searching? Thank you very much!

Comment: When you execute a batch script, you transfer control to it (to never come back to the original script). Use `call "C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat"` to continue the original script when the called script ends or `start "StartEdge" "C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat"` to start it as an independent process and resume the original script immediately. (you can use `start /min ...` to start it minimized, if wished) (the first quoted parameter acts as a WindowTitle)

Comment: Using "call" its still opening the script that I want to use and closing the script you gave me. Maybe im puting the call command on wrong line. I add it after first condition of IF

Comment: My script is basically an infinite loop and doesn't exit on its own (except you introduced a severe syntax error). An `exit` command in the called script will end the session (including all running scripts). `Start` will not have this problem.

Comment: I have only added "start C:\BookOfSixNew\ShellStartEdge.bat" after "echo Found a new monitor" which make the script to shut down after executing the command. Same thing doing with call cmd.

Comment: Works fine for me. If I had to bet, I would say you have a syntax error/typo with the second `if` statement. Run from an open `cmd` window with `echo on` to see what's really executed. (Sorry, but I'm afk for a few hours now)

Comment: I found the problem. Opening the .bat file its making the script to close. I tried with an .exe file and its working perfectly. Now i have to figure out how to open .bat file without making the script to close.

Comment: Check the opened batch file for an `exit` command and replace it with `exit /b` or `goto :eof